# how to fix button at end of Listview item are completed?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listContact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:divider="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    >
</ListView>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnContactPostYourEnquiry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="POST YOUR ENQUIRY"
        android:background="@drawable/contact_post" 
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listContact"/>
```

I am try to display the PastEnqury Button at the end of listview not the   end of screen but output is only listview is display button is not display if list item is more i.e listview have to scroll 
I am writting this code in Relative Layout

Comment: Remove `RelativeLayout` Put your `ListView` and `Button` in `FrameLayout` and set button `Gravity` as `Bottom`

Comment: DownVoters mention the reason for your down vote

Comment: Add button as a footer to listview

Comment: alignParentBottom true for the button

Comment: I am trying Frame layout button is display bottom of screen not a bottom of ListView

Comment: alignParentBottom display the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am solve the problem by adding List Footer View

layout_contact_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="fill_vertical" 
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/action_button" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listContact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:divider="@drawable/background"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:scrollingCache="true" >

</ListView>
```

contact_footer_view.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnContactPostYourEnquiry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="POST YOUR ENQUIRY"
        android:background="@drawable/contact_post" 
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
```

mainActivity.java

```
    ListView list_Contact=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listContact);

    FrameLayout footerLayout = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_footer_view,null);
    Button btnPostYourEnquiry = (Button) footerLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnContactPostYourEnquiry);
    list_Contact.addFooterView(footerLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Button as your ListView Footer. This way, it will be part of your ListView and you can scroll down to it.

Comment: thanks my problem is solve by addind footerView to list

Comment: Would you mind marking it as solution if it solved your problem? This way it is easier for people coming to this site.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in relative layout eg is given in code below  `android:layout_above="@+id/linear"` this will put your listview above other layout ,just replace ExpandableListView with ListView

```
 <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#000000"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I got error that custom adapter can not set to the ExpandableListView

Comment: change ExpandableListView to ListView in xml

Comment: ExpandableListView was used by me in my project it of no use to you ,if you are using listview continue using it

Comment: my issue is I want to display the button at the bottum of ListView not the bottom of screen

Comment: hey add button in your layout but set its visiblity Gone then count the number of elements in list on last element set all other views visiblity Gone and make the button Visible

Comment: button.setVisibility(View.GONE); some thing like this

Comment: there no any effect of visibility ... button putting after listview can not display

Comment: move to chat and show me your code so that i can help u on it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49403/discussion-between-user3392323-and-auto-droid-)

Answer (score 0):

Programetically set the height of list view

for e.g.

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, your_array.size() * 120);

nd in xml add button bellow listview in linear layout